# Implementing managed configurations in NativeScript

Tags: android, nativescript, android-restrictions

I am developing a NativeScript app for android and wish to implement managed configurations as described here: https://developer.android.com/work/managed-configurations.html.

I have tried adding app_restrictions.xml to the App_Resources/Android/values folder but I get the following build error:

> Execution failed for task ':mergeF0F1DebugResources'.
>   Error: Unsupported type 'restriction'

This is the content of app_restrictions.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<restrictions xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <restriction
    android:key="downloadOnCellular"
    android:restrictionType="bool"
    android:defaultValue="true" />
</restrictions>
```

Does NativeScript support adding restrictions like this? If so, how do I add the restriction resource file. If not, is there some other way to implement managed configurations?

EDIT: Solved by pkanev in the comments. The restrictions file must be placed in App_Resources/Android/xml.

Comment: I think the file should go in in an `xml` directory, and not inside `values`. Could you test that?

Comment: The build was successful, I'll try to see if the restriction manager can access the values.

Comment: It works, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the official Android documentation - https://developer.android.com/work/managed-configurations.html
the restrictions configuration needs to be placed in `res/xml` dir, which corresponds to `app/App_Resources/Android/xml` in a NativeScript Android app.